# Make UITableViewCell actions overlap content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was trying to go about making the actions for a UITableViewCell overlap the content of the cell, like in the National Geographic app:

[table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgaZp.png)
[table view when swiped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTylK.png)

I tried using a listener on the contentView of the cell to track the frame and keep it constant, but I was unable to get that to work (although it's possible it would, I'm kinda new to iOS).

If anyone has any suggestions for creating a similar effect, they would be much appreciated!

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Ketan I was hoping to make it so that when the cell is swiped, the delete action appears overtop of the cell as opposed to pushing the content to the side like in the mail app in [this image](http://www.everything-email.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Untitled-23.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can make your own custom cell and add a delete button and swipe gestures to make like button overlap the contents of the cell for example, try it out yourself, first create a sample project with single view app, and proceed

subclass the tabview cell with xib option selected and name it something like `CustomCell` , and in `CustomCell.swift` class past below code

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

var deleteButton:UIButton!

//create a custom cell if not in the reuse pool
class  func  customCell() -> CustomCell?
{
        let aVar:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomCell", owner: nil, options: nil)

        if aVar.last!.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell)
        {
            return aVar.last as? CustomCell
        }
        return nil
}

//handle your left swipe
func swipeLeft()
{
    print("swipe Left")
    self.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(deleteButton!)
    var frameRect:CGRect! = deleteButton!.frame
    frameRect.origin.x = self.contentView.bounds.size.width - self.deleteButton!.frame.size.width
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        self.deleteButton!.frame = frameRect
    }
}

//aslo the right swipe
func swipeRight()
{
    print("swipe right")
    var rect:CGRect! = deleteButton?.frame
    rect.origin.x = self.contentView.bounds.size.width
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        self.deleteButton!.frame = rect
    }
}

//hear we are adding the delete button in code, if u want add it in xib or (if u are using storyboard )
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    deleteButton = UIButton.init(type: .Custom)
    deleteButton.setTitle("Delete", forState: .Normal)
    deleteButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.contentView.addSubview(deleteButton)


    let gestureLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: "swipeLeft")
    gestureLeft.direction = .Left
    self .addGestureRecognizer(gestureLeft)

    let gestureRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: "swipeRight")
    gestureRight.direction = .Right
    self .addGestureRecognizer(gestureRight)

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

//set the initial frame of delete button 
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var rect:CGRect! = deleteButton?.frame
    rect.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    rect.origin.x = self.contentView.bounds.size.width
    deleteButton?.frame = rect
}
}
```

and make sure the tableview cell height to be of 100pt and in view controller set up a tableview in storyboard with datasource and delegate and  implement the required delegate and datasource  methods

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? CustomCell
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = CustomCell .customCell()
    }
    return cell as CustomCell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```